# How to hyphen compound attribute names in a Spring Controllers Json response with Katharsis.io

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, ember-data, json-api

The [Json:API](http://jsonapi.org/) <s>requires</s> recommends compound attribute names to be hyphened (like first-name)

```
...
{
"type": "people",
"id": "9",
"attributes": {
  "first-name": "Foo",
  "last-name": "Bar",
}
...
```

In Java hyphened attribute names are not valid identifiers.

I'm using [Katharsis](http://katharsis.io/) 2.0.1 to build a JSON:API based service backend within spring-boot 1.3.0. My calling/consuming frontend app is build with Ember 2.0 and ember-data.

Unfortunately Katharsis doesn't seem to convert compound attribute names in Java to hypehened attribute names in Json.

This is a result Katharsis generates for a resource  GET */api/customers*

```
{
 "data": [
   {
     "type": "customers",
     "id": "1",
     "attributes": {
       "cpn": "-1234567",
       "firstName": "John",
  },
  ...
```

But it should be **"first-name": "John"**

Am I missing some configuration or how do I tell Katharsis do hyphen attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Ethans advice I stick with camelCase attributes in Katharsis.io and let Ember override the attribute names.

In Ember the **JSONAPISerializer** supports all cases in the sense that it provides hooks that are easily overridden. The docs for [keyForAttribute](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#method_keyForAttribute) and [keyForRelationship](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#method_keyForRelationship) shows examples of how to customize keys.

In my case I had to implement the following serializer class:

```
// app/application/serializer.js or app/serializers/application.js 

import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
 keyForAttribute: function(attr, method) {
  return Ember.String.camelize(attr);
},

 keyForRelationship: function(key, relationship, method) {
  return Ember.String.camelize(key);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON:API doesn't require that multi-word attributes use a hyphen; it just [recommends](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#naming) that they do.

And that recommendation, imo, is stupid for exactly the reasons you describe. It just makes interoperability harder. So my advice would just be to ignore the recommendation and stick with camelCase attributes. Again, there's nothing about doing that that is prohibited.

Some (stupid) tools may assume your API follows the dasherized recommendation. But if a tool assumes that, and doesn't give you a way to override that assumption, then it's a bug in that tool, and you'll be doing the community a favor by showing the tool's authors that they need to support all valid JSON:API usage, not just that which follows the recommendation.

P.S. While the above is just my opinion/advice, I am one of JSON:API's editors, so it is an informed opinion and the facts I mention (e.g. about dasherizing just being a recommendation) are correct.

Comment: You’re absolutely right an I agree with you!
In my particular problem the (stupid) tool Ember wasn’t so stupid after all. Ember assumes your API follows the dasherized recommendation but also provides a way to override the recommended way.
Through your advice I found out what I had to look for an could find a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In newest version is added support for [PropertyNamingStrategy](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturePropertyNamingStrategy) from jackson , so that hyphening names is available.

Comment: I'm facing some problems updating to the newest version of Katharsis. But I'll let you know and update my question/answer as soon as I got it working. Cheers

Comment: link is dead btw